# Windows store app Post with multipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, java, android, windows-store-apps

I`m porting Android java App to C#, Windows store app. it must send POST to server with multipart content, image and some key/value data.
java code:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entity.addPart(filename, new ByteArrayBody(byteArray, "image/jpeg", filename + ".jpg"));
        entity.addPart("usr", new StringBody(user));
        entity.addPart("sid", new StringBody(session));
        entity.addPart("action", new StringBody(method));
        post.setEntity(entity);
```

and Windows Store code:

```
  MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
        multipartContent.Add(byteContent, fileName);                
        multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(User), "usr");
        multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(Session), "sid");
        multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(method), "action");
```

But server respond with differend responses. What could it be?

Comment: More information please. Is it your server? Or a 3rd party server you have no control over? If it's your own, do you have an code which relies on UserAgent (browser string)?

Comment: no, it isn`t my server

Comment: Then try setting user agent manually and use same UserAgent and see if the results still differ

Comment: @Tseng Could you please discribe it more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

If the server determines output by user-agent, then try setting same UserAgent on both Apps.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

```
// UserAgent taken from http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Android%20Webkit%20Browser/
// Pick one you find suitable or use Firefox/Chrome UserAgents, whatever works for you
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; fr-fr; HTC Desire Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.getInstance(userAgent);
httpClient.execute(post);
```

C#/.NET

```
// make sure to use same user agent in both apps
string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; fr-fr; HTC Desire Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent",userAgent);
```

That should give you same results, if the server returns different results based on user-agent header.